# How to get Custom Item Field in netsuite php toolkit 2012.2?

Tags: php, netsuite

Here is my code:

```
$service    = new NetSuiteService();
$getRequest = new GetRequest();
$getRequest->baseRef = new RecordRef();
$getRequest->baseRef->internalId = "custitem3";
$getRequest->baseRef->type = "itemCustomField";

$result = $service->get($getRequest);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

And the result is: That record does not exist.

But that custom item field show in **Set up > Customization > Item fields** in netsuite backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anwser is: internal id must send in uppercase: CUSTITEM3

Answer (score 0):

If you are after the value of the custom item field, the item record itself should be loaded.

Comment: I want to get its description.

Comment: You could be more specific in your question.